# panel1.DrawToBitmap doesn't draw lines from DrawLine

Tags: c#, visual-studio, jpeg, system.drawing, drawtobitmap

I have a panel on which I'm drawing lines using:

```
Point PreviousPoint = new Point (0,0);
Point NewPoint = new Point (10,10);
Pen MyPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2);
Graphics MyGraphics = panel1.CreateGraphics();
MyGraphics.DrawLine(MyPen, PreviousPoint, NewPoint);
```

This all works fine.  I obviously change the points to draw more lines, but that doesn't matter for this question.  I want to export that panel as a jpg file.  I'm using this code:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(panel1.Width, panel1.Height);
panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, panel1.Width, panel1.Height));
bmp.Save("C:\\panel.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

This outputs a blank jpg.  The background of my panel is gray, and the background of the jpg is the same gray, so I know it's actually exporting the panel.  Also, I added a button into the panel just to see if it would get saved, and it did.  So for some reason the jpg isn't saving the lines being drawn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I made a workaround that solves the core problem.  I made an array of the points I plotted to draw the lines, then I did this:

```
        // make sure you actually drew something
        if (MyLines.Length > 0)
        {
            // instantiate the stuff you need
            Image img = new Bitmap(panel1.Width, panel1.Height);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(img);
            Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2);

            // draw every line (from every even index to the one after it)
            for (int i = 0; i < MyLines.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i % 2 == 0)
                {
                    g.DrawLine(pen, MyLines[i], MyLines[i + 1]);
                }
            }
            img.Save("C:\\panel.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        }
    }
```